# what about a newbie tag ?

Tags: discussion

I'm torn. I'd love to have a newbie tag to browse and learn things at my level, but I also realize that sometimes is not easy to say what is "newbie" and what is not. Also it would require a lot of effort to tag what it's already in the database, I guess.

What do you think about it ?

Comment: This makes no sense.  A question could be beginner level, but the answers might not be.  If you are looking for *information*, then it's the characteristics of the answers you care about.  There is no way to rate the level of answers, only how good they are.  I don't see how what you propose could be made to work.

Comment: Advocating for the creation of a meta-tag...[no.  No god please no.  Noooooo.](http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/14900000/The-Office-gifs-the-office-14948948-240-196.gif)

Answer (score 7):

Definitely not.  Not only is 'newbie' very informal, but we already have [beginner], which is (unfortunately for those trying to make the site more professional-oriented) the fifth-most popular tag.

The following was true Oct 3 '10. The tag has since been removed.

You can read all 47 questions currently tagged [beginner] here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner.  This URL has a few features which were not present in Chiphacker's SE 1.0 platform, such as a wiki, an FAQ, an About page, and various ways of viewing users and questions in the tag.  If you were interested in tagging these questions, perhaps you'd be interested in drafting these pages?  The place to discuss that would be a separate question here on meta.  See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58052/great-example-questions-in-the-c-tag) on meta.SO for an example of how this was done for the C tag.

Comment: You should be happy that people tag beginner. This means you can filter out beginner questions and have a "more professional site".

Answer (score 3):

No. Tags should give an indication about the question's topic(s), nothing else. That's the reason the `homework` tag is deprecated too, for instance. If you want to indicate that you're a beginner in order to get answers at your level of knowledge, say so in the question.

If there would be any need to have an indication about difficulty level, like the number of chef's caps in kitchen recipes, that should be something separate, but I don't advocate this. Like Olin says levels can be different for different answers, and there's nothing wrong with that; answers should be as widely useful as possible. So if you're lost at the second sentence of an answer, move on to the next.

After all, if you're looking up questions it will be based on "555" rather than "beginner".

PS: I notice there are 25 questions tagged `learning`, I think that tag should go as well.